# Extract rates near to the percent sign

Tags: regex, r

Having a vector characters like this

```
  c("E_B_V_BNOW_UN_3%_01-02-2016",
    "E_B_V_XX_3%_20%_01-02-2016",
    "E_B_YY_25%_3%_20%_01-02-2016")
```

I would like to extract the rates near to the `%`?

I can do it using a combination of `strsplit` and `gsub` but is it a way to do it using a single regular expression?

The expect output is :

```
list(c(3),c(3,20),c(25,3,20))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
regmatches(s, gregexpr("\\d+(?=%)", s, perl = TRUE))
# [[1]]
# [1] "3"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "3"  "20"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "25" "3"  "20"
```

Comment: as written, the answer doesn't match the expected output (list of numeric vectors)

Comment: "[0-9.]+(?=%)" would allow decimal valued numbers and "[0-9.E]+(?=%)" would allow an even wider range at the expense of possible errors. I think there are SO threads on what would constitute a safe alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Use `stringr::str_extract_all`.

```
s <- c("E_B_V_BNOW_UN_3%_01-02-2016",
      "E_B_V_XX_3%_20%_01-02-2016",
      "E_B_YY_25%_3%_20%_01-02-2016")

library("stringr")
str_extract_all(s, "\\d+%")
```

Or to get rid of the percentages and make it numeric, you can do:

```
lapply(str_extract_all(s, "\\d+(?=%)"), as.numeric)
```

As has been pointed out by other answerers.  This uses a [positive lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: @DavidArenburg right, edited to get rid of percentages

Comment: also note that `as.numeric` is required to return numeric (not character) results